# com.sun.net.httpserver error, what does is mean?

Tags: java, permission-denied, httpserver, socketexception

My code looks like this :

```
    import com.sun.net.httpserver.*;
    import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
    ...

    void Srart_Server()
    {
      ....
      InetSocketAddress addr=new InetSocketAddress(80);
      HttpServer server=HttpServer.create(addr,0);      // Line : 32
```

It ran OK on my PC, but after I copied the app to Linux and ran it, I got the following error :

```
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl.<init>(ServerImpl.java:100)
        at sun.net.httpserver.HttpServerImpl.<init>(HttpServerImpl.java:50)
        at sun.net.httpserver.DefaultHttpServerProvider.createHttpServer(DefaultHttpServerProvider.java:35)
        at com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer.create(HttpServer.java:130)
        at Http_Server.Srart_Server(Http_Server.java:32)
```

Why ? How to fix that ?

Comment: Most probably the port you are trying to start the server on is already occupied. Try with a less popular port - 8080 or 8888

Comment: In that case ther errormessage would read: "Address already in use".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**A firewall on your remote machine** (linux) does not allow your java code to open a port. This needs to be fixed based on the linux distro and firewall (+network settings).

As a possible fix you can try to open the port 8080. Some unix machines will reserve all ports below 1024 for root users.